# C# SQL statement - Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2003

Below is the code I have, I can't for the life of me work out what is wrong with the query.

I originally had the error "no value given for 1 or more parameters", which seems to have gone away (although again I don't even know why I was getting it).

The connection is opened prior to this code.
The parameter GVars.thisFY is a string = "FY13" - this table definitely exists.
The parameter GVars.currentDate is a DateTime = today.

Records definitely exist for this [Destination] and [Next Collection] range:

```
string sql;
OleDbDataAdapter adapter;

sql = "SELECT * FROM @CurFY WHERE [Destination] = @Destination AND [Next Collection] BETWEEN @NextCollectionA AND @NextCollectionB;";

// Create the command object
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = sql;

// Add values to the fields
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurFY", GVars.thisFY);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", "Henwood");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextCollectionA", GVars.currentDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextCollectionB", GVars.currentDate.AddDays(1));

adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn);

try
{
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    GVars.bLblLastUpdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

EDIT:
I have changed the code to remove the table parameter as below, still getting the "no value given for 1 or more parameters" though which I can't pin down..

EDIT2: I removed the extra stuff so the post relates only to the original question, which has been answered. I will make a new question for my strange "no value given" error

Comment: You can't have the table name as a parameter. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124261/odbccommand-parametrization-with-table-name

Comment: your main mistake here was swallowing the exception; there are very few good places to do that, and this isn't one of them

Comment: What **database system** (and which version) are you using? SQL is just the query language - and it's used by many database systems, that doesn't really tell us anything....

Comment: the database is in Access (2003-2003 format)

Comment: @Marc Gravell what do you mean? The catch block is empty since I'm only using it to see the error my coding is producing, once this is sorted I will add a less generalized catch for network/database issues etc. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot parameterize queries with names of tables, views, or columns. Only data members can be parameterized.

You need to make your SQL dynamically, e.g. like this:

```
sql = string.Format(
    "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE [Destination] = @Destination AND [Next Collection] BETWEEN @NextCollectionA AND @NextCollectionB;"
,  GVars.thisFY
);
```

This should be done only if `GVars.thisFY` is controlled by your code, e.g. comes from a pre-defined list or checked for absence of non-alphanumeric characters to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: don't i feel stupid... ok removed that parameter, now it tells me again that there is no value given for 1 or more parameters

Comment: If GVars.thisFY somehow comes from the client (e.g. a dropdown, which could be manually altered), this would impose a security vulnerability. Sanitise your input before sticking it into a query.

Comment: @IanAbbott "no value given for 1 or more parameters" That's strange... Did you also remove the `@` from the query? Your query should have only 3 `@`s now, and there should be 3 calls of `AddWithValue` in the code.

Comment: i have updated my original post with the current revised code

Comment: @IanAbbott Your edited version should have worked (not sure about the the semicolon at the end, but I did not work with MS Access through C#, so I cannot say for sure).

Comment: no, doesn't work...I tried it with and without the semi-colon on the end (though I don't put a semi-colon on the end usually and have no problems)

Comment: @IanAbbott Just a suggestion: The code would be more robust (and perhaps somewhat safer, too) if the table name was enclosed in square brackets, i.e., `SELECT * FROM [{0}] ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
sql = Sring.Format(
    "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE [Destination] = @Destination AND [Next Collection] BETWEEN @NextCollectionA AND @NextCollectionB;", 
    GVars.thisFY
)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", "Henwood");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextCollectionA", GVars.currentDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextCollectionB", GVars.currentDate.AddDays(1));
```

Comment: If GVars.thisFY somehow comes from the client (e.g. a dropdown, which could be manually altered), this would impose a security vulnerability. Sanitise your input before sticking it into a query.